# WP7: How to remove binding from code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I have a TextBlock tblControl and I want to set a binding 
similar to xaml's

`Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}"`

but in code. So I use:

```
var b = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("ForegroundColor") };
tblControl.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, b);
```

Everything works.

Now I want to remove Binding to allow a TextBlock to show default Foreground color or I need to set default value of Foreground. `tblControl.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, null);` is NOT WORKING. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will clear a binding (or any other local value):

```
tblControl.ClearValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
```